# Jquery tab container not working (not detecting ,tabs() function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I am trying to use jquery tab container. I have added all the files which include js and css files as shown here on jquery site http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

But in intellisense the .tabs() function is not showing.

Any idea why is this the case

I am including files on page like this

```
<link href="Styles/tabs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/tabs1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/tabs2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the tab1 file is jquery v1.10.2 and tab2 is ui js file

here is html

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="Styles/tabs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/tabs1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/tabs2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    function abc() { }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<div id="tabs"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: `intellisense` of which IDE/text-editor.

Comment: @Jai visual studio 2010

Comment: @FrebinFrancis I have posted html

Answer (score 0):

**HTML and Script**

Use your plugin method inside document.ready() event.

For readability purpose properly name your script files with version included

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>     
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">First Tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second Tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third Tab</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>First Tab</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Second Tab
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Third Tab</p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```